# how to push two commits separately in git

Tags: git

I wanted to make two independent changes through branch 1 and branch 2. However, after committing changes through branch 1, I directly used 'git checkout -b branch 2'. thereby including commit from branch 1 into branch 2. I do have a commit related to branch 2 that I want to commit, but I want to ignore the commit from branch 1. What is the way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

you can do an interactive rebase.

if A is the common branch and B1 and B2 the branches, then from B2 if you do
`git rebase -i A`

then you can choose to delete the B1 commit.

```
A ---B1
      \
       \
        B2
```

interactive rebase from B2 to A will prompt an editor like

```
pick COMMIT_FROM_B2 message
pick COMMIT_FROM_B2 message
pick COMMIT_FROM_B2 message
pick COMMIT_FROM_B1 message
pick COMMIT_FROM_B1 message
pick COMMIT_FROM_B1 message
pick COMMIT_FROM_A  message
```

by deleting the B1 lines you can accomplish your target and keep only the `B2` commits.

Answer (score 0):

`git checkout -b branch2` is equivalent to `git checkout -b branch2 HEAD`, i.e. use the current commit as the starting point for the branch. If you're not happy with that just replace HEAD with whatever commit you want to start the branch from. To start branch2 from the parent commit of the tip of branch1 (i.e. skip the most recent commit on branch1), run `git checkout -b branch2 branch1~`.

In your case, if you want to correct things after the fact, you could delete branch2 and recreate it from the correct starting point. This of course assumes that you haven't committed anything to the branch. Instead of deleting and recreating the branch you can instead forcefully change what the branch pointer pionts at with `git reset --hard branch1~` (assuming branch2 is checked out).